# Parse data in Google Answers Box?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, google-search

[image: Here is google's Answer Box]

Stolen from [here.](http://cognitiveseo.com/blog/6266/decoding-google-answer-box-algorithm-serp-research-10-353-keywords/)

I would like to be able to get the content out of this box, and using PHP. I would like to know what you all think, should I used php's Simple HTML DOM Parser[(like this example)](http://blog.proscraper.com/web-scraping/65/scraping-and-parsing-google-search-results-with-the-php-simple-html-dom-library), or use the [Google Custom Search function](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/). I am specifically trying to get data out of that "box", and would like to know what the community here thinks.

EDIT!!! I would also like to add that I would be using the "define:" (followed by a word) function of google. As google dictionary has been discontinued, I would like a way to use this function.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @jmelosegui I have tried the parsing method, it works decently well but is a CPU hog. I will try to optimize the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a Q&A parser and am currently using a couple different methods. The custom search API doesn't seem to return the specific answers so I've been parsing normal web search. As with all web scraping, you are at the mercy of the page architecture, but here are a couple methods that I've had success with so far.

First of all, I inject a jQuery. This is because I'm using node.js and a quasi dom emulator, but any selector engine on another platform would obviously work.

```
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
  newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
  newscript.async = true;
  newscript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();
```

I'm detecting [straight answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20get%20text%20of%20element&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=what%20is%20lebron%20james%20birthday) like this:

```
$('#center_col').find("[role='heading']").children('div').first().text()
```

Another common type is the [card](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20google%20search%20parse&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=what%20is%20the%20planck%20length) like you've given an example of above. I'm guessing there could be an element/attribute pattern that might be workable like the method above, but I've realized that it's much easier to go after design aspects of the elements since all the attributes are scrambled and certain aesthetics are less likely to change IMO.

```
$('#center_col').find('div').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('box-shadow') == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 4px 0px";
}).find('span').first().text()
```

Good luck!